# Is it possible to run 2 motors independently with USB?

Tags: microcontroller, usb, servo, robotics, android

Is it possible to run two motors independently in both directions with usb using no microcontroller but just some discrete components?

I'm trying to create the cheapest possible robot that can just move about via two motors that can be run independently, for rotation, and rotated cw or ccw for going backwards. This robot must be controlled by an android device through USB.

Can this be done without any microcontroller?

I'm not creating this just for fun but also as a prototype so I'd like it to be as cost efficient as possible.

Comment: Are you willing to use a cheap usb adapter? If you use a USB->Parallel (old style printer) connector, that gives you direct access to several IO lines you can use to directly control an H-bridge.

Answer (score 1):

You could buy one of these: -

[image]

[Here](http://www.rapidonline.com/Design-Technology/USB-Experiment-Interface-Board-Electronics-Kit-70-4314/?source=googleps&utm_source=googleps&IncVat=1&gclid=CKqS48qBw8MCFUHlwgodb6kAgQ) is the link - the board cost about £20 and is described as: -

> The Velleman USB Experiment Interface Board Kit has 5 digital input
>   channels and 8 digital output channels, plus two analogue inputs and
>   two analogue outputs with 8 bit resolution. The number of
>   inputs/outputs can be further expanded by connecting up to 4 more
>   cards to the PC's USB connectors. All communication routines are
>   contained in a Dynamic Link Library (DLL). You may write custom
>   Windows (XP, Vista, Windows7) applications in Delphi, Visual Basic,
>   C++ Builder or any other 32-bit Windows application development tool
>   that supports calls to a DLL. Also available as a pre-assembled
>   module.

If you are hoping to get away without writing software then you may be disappointed.

Answer (score 1):

*usb using no microcontroller but just some discrete components*

It is not possible to do *anything* with USB other than draw the continuous 5V from the supply lines without a microcontroller or an ASIC. Theoretically you can turn the 5V off from the computer side but this isn't normally easy to get at in the drivers.

For practical purposes your best option is one of the existing breakout or motor control USB boards.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible without a motor control board and/or a microcontroller . Depending on the motor, they usually require a lot of current to run, which cannot be supplied by a USB . And if you need to reverse the polarity from CW to ACW , then USB would clearly not be able to do that without an external control board.

In either case almost all motors would need more than the current a USB can supply. SO you will be using the voltage output as a USB to just provide the signal to keep a switch  on/off but an external power source to provide the amperage.